# If stock A has a 60% chance of rising, and stocks A and B have 80% correlation, what is the chance of stock B rising?

Tags: correlation, probability

As in the subject, I'm interested in a math puzzle of sorts:

If stock A has a 60% chance of rising, and stocks A and B have an 80% correlation, what is the chance of stock B rising?

Would it be possible to extend this concept so that if we know the probabilities of stocks A,B,C,D rising, we can work out the probability of stock E rising, given tha stock E has some correlation to stocks A,B,C,D?

**Update:**

For an indepth tutorial video on the basics of probability, see the [Khan Academy Tutorial Videos on Probability](http://www.khanacademy.org/video/probability--part-1?playlist=Probability).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't determine this with just the correlation; you need to know the joint probability.